# Brute force all possible matrix combinations in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, brute-force

I've currently created a 3x3 matrix in python using numpy (initializing every value to 0). I would like to create a small python program that brute forces EVERY possible KEY combination in the matrix. For example:

```
[1, 0, 0
 0, 0, 0
 0, 0, 0]

[1, 1, 0
 0, 0, 0
 0, 0, 0]
```

etc... all the way to:

```
[9, 9, 9
 9, 9, 9
 9, 9, 9]
```

Seems very trivial but for some reason can't wrap my head around it.
The reason I'm doing this is because I want to get the inverse of EVERY matrix combination (which is easy using numpy) and multiply it by another matrix until I get a solution I'm looking for... Essentially I'm trying to brute for the Crypto Hill Cipher.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's a "KEY" combination?

Comment: Don't you mean `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`?

Comment: @user2357112: a non-singular 3x3 matrix with multiplication performed in the ring modulo the size of the alphabet (usually 26, in this case apparently 10).

Comment: If it's supposed to be nonsingular, none of the examples appear to be valid.

Comment: @user2357112: that's true. The questioner doesn't say, but keys in the Hill cipher must have an inverse for decryption. I'm guessing that the questioner's first step is to iterate over everything, and singular matrices will be eliminated later either explicitly or because they can't possibly be the correct key. I mentioned it in case anyone knows a way to prune the search space a bit given that constraint.

Comment: Yup @SteveJessop, exactly my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it i think.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import numpy as np

x = np.empty((3,3), dtype=int)

for comb in combinations_with_replacement(range(10),9):
    x.flat[:] = comb
```

Comment: You sir, can have my babies. Thank you!

Comment: Oh hang there...the function x.I doesn't work =[ (I = inverse from numpy). Is there anyway around this...or do I have to now calculate inverse by myself? >_>

Comment: What's the error message? You you might have to defined X as a matrix instead of an array.

Comment: The error message is: 'numpy.ndarry' object has no attribute I. Even if I try using the linalg.inv(x) function, I get 'Singular Matrix'... How would I go about fixing this? =/

Comment: You would have to break math to invert a Singular matrix. Not all matrices are invertable. If you do `x = np.matrix(x)` before the loop, you can use x.I. But it will still give an error for singular matrices.

Comment: @JakeZ: if the matrix is singular then it is not the key. Suppose the key is all zeroes: then every plain text maps to cipher text all zeroes. So how would you decrypt it? The matrix having an inverse *means* that it's possible to decipher, because having an inverse means that no two distinct plain texts map to the same cipher text.

Answer (score 2):

If your alphabet is just the 10 digits then what you're doing there is technically called "counting in base 10" ;-)

At each step increment the last digit (bottom right). If it was 9, wrap it around to 0 and increment the next-to-last digit, and so on until after 10 billion steps the top digit wraps.

It might also be possible to do something more efficient with `itertools.product`, but since that doesn't produce the numpy matrices you need, maybe not.

If your alphabet is 26 characters then you might be waiting a while for this to finish running, since 26**10 is a rather large number.